# Testing an overridden action on Spree Controller Decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spree

I am having issues testing an overridden action of an Spree Controller Decorator that looks like this:

```
app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller_decorator.rb

Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do
  def update
     do_something
     redirect_to my_other_path
  end
end
```

The spec I have is:

```
spec/controllers/spree/checkout_controller_spec.rb

describe Spree::CheckoutController do
  routes { Spree::Core::Engine.routes }

  it "does something" do
    put :update
  end
end
```

but it is never getting in my update definition, it is getting to the Spree original definition.

Answer (score 2):

I tried reproducing the your above mentioned problem. I did run into the same problem.
But after I looked into the test logs, For me it was complaining

`Filter chain halted as :ensure_checkout_allowed rendered or redirected`

Because of which the overridden controller was never executed. It failed even before it reached the overridden method.

This is what my spec file looks like:
spec/controllers/checkout_controller_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Spree::CheckoutController do
  let(:order) {FactoryGirl.create(:spree_order)}

  before(:each) do
    @routes = Spree::Core::Engine.routes
    controller.stub :check_authorization => true
    controller.stub :ensure_checkout_allowed => true
    controller.stub :ensure_valid_state => true
    controller.stub :current_order => order
  end

  it "does something" do
    user = create(:spree_user)
    user.spree_roles.create(:name => "admin")
    sign_in(user)

    puts @routes.inspect
    spree_put :update, :order => {}
    assigns(:test_obj).should eql(1)
  end
end
```

This is what my overridden controller file looks like:
/app/controller/spree/checkout_controller_decorator.rb

```
Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do
  def update
    @test_obj = 1
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

You might have to stub some `before_filters` or write some code to make the `before_filters` pass